# .NET CORE Razor Pages Ajax call to C# method

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am currently making a site to display locations on a google map. I get the location addresses from an Airtable.com database and everything there is working fine. However because google only allow a certain number of request to geocode addresses, i want to save the coordinates in the same database, so i only use the geocode api when a new location(address) needs to be looked up. I got that all setup, but i can't seem to figure out how i call a cs method from js in razor pages. I have used WebMethod in the past but i can't use that here apparently.

When i try to use the examples i find online, it says i need the RequestVerificationToken, but that needs the call to come from within a form(am i right?), and my ajax call is prompted when the site loads and it gets a location from the database which does not have any coordinates yet.

This is my first time using Razor Pages, so bear with me if i have totally misunderstood something.

Picture of my cs method i would like to call (Index.cshtml.cs)
[I tried with the httpPost tag, but it didn't make a difference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnqdQ.png)

```
    [HttpPost] // RequestVerificationToken
    public void OnPostGeoLocation()
    {
        // Just to test that it actually gets called
        Console.WriteLine("OnPostGeoLocation CALLED ####################################");
        Console.WriteLine("OnPostGeoLocation CALLED ####################################");
        Console.WriteLine("OnPostGeoLocation CALLED ####################################");
        Console.WriteLine("OnPostGeoLocation CALLED ####################################");
    }
```

Picture of Ajax call from JavaScript, which is called on page load basically: [AjaxCall](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvwOD.png)

```
function updateRow(recordID, latLng) {
   console.log("REC_ID: " + recordID);
   console.log("LatLng: " + latLng);
   $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: '/Index?OnPostGeoLocation', 
       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       dataType: "json"
   }).done(function (data) {
       console.log(data.result);
   })
 }
```

Im aware that some of the code is not exactly what i need, but i just copied from online and will edit when im ahead of this hurdle .

Comment: Show more of the PageModel in a [mcve]. I would also suggest Reference [Introduction to Razor Pages in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-2.0&tabs=visual-studio)

Comment: From what I can tell you are having problems with [XSRF/CSRF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery?view=aspnetcore-2.0) depending on configuration I think you need to add the header in your ajax call

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try returning a proper `IActionResult` result.

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult OnPostGeoLocation() {
    // Just to test that it actually gets called
    Console.WriteLine("OnPostGeoLocation CALLED ####################################");

    return new JsonResult("OnPostGeoLocation CALLED ####################################");
}
```

Next when making the call you need to call the correct handler path and include the anti-forgery token becasue, Razor Pages are designed to be automatically protected from cross-site request forgery (CSRF/XSRF) attacks.

Updated Ajax call

```
function updateRow(recordID, latLng) {
    console.log("REC_ID: " + recordID);
    console.log("LatLng: " + latLng);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/Index?handler=GeoLocation', 
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
                $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
        },
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json"
    }).done(function (data) {
        console.log(data.result);
    })
}
```

Very helpful article for reference

[Handle Ajax Requests in ASP.NET Core Razor Pages](http://www.talkingdotnet.com/handle-ajax-requests-in-asp-net-core-razor-pages/)

Comment: Oh, yes, that's just a typo. It shows the OnPostGeoLocation in the picture.
When i change the ? to a slash(/) i get a 404 not found error instead of the no VerficationToken error. I will look into the links you both provided and get back if i still cant seem to figure it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

After reading [Handle Ajax Requests in ASP.NET Core Razor Pages](http://www.talkingdotnet.com/handle-ajax-requests-in-asp-net-core-razor-pages/) more carefully i figured out that i had indeed misunderstood some of the principles and that you CAN add AntiForgeryToken explicitly without a "form" tag, using @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

My code look like this now: 
[image]

And:

[image]

Comment: Just one thing you don't need to use before send you have `headers` object in the call. Also this can be configured globally so you don't need this for every [ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/).

Comment: You are correct and I made a mistake in my answer with the handler as well. fixing.